# scala Play Framework 2.4: sending email

Tags: scala, email, playframework, playframework-2.4

I trying to send an email from scala Play framework 2.4 while using [play-mailer](https://github.com/playframework/play-mailer), I have followed the instruction from their sample page but with no success.

I have added the dependency to build.sbt:

```
libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
  "com.typesafe.play" %% "play-mailer" % "3.0.1"
)
```

In application.conf the I have added the following:

```
play.mailer {
    host=smtp.gmail.com
    port=465 
    ssl=true
    tls=true
    user="testme@gmail.com"
    password=abracadabra
}
```

And finally, the Mailing Class:

```
package controllers

import java.io.File
import javax.inject.Inject
import org.apache.commons.mail.EmailAttachment
import play.api.Configuration
import play.api.Play.current
import play.api.libs.mailer._

class Mail(mailer: MailerClient) {
  def send = {
    val cid = "1234"
    val email = Email(
      "Simple email",
      "Mister FROM <from@email.com>",
      Seq("Miss TO <to@email.com>"),
      bodyText = Some("A text message"),
      bodyHtml = Some("some data....")
    )
    mailer.send(email)
  }
}
```

So far without compilation errors, however I don't understand how to initialize this class.. how should I get the "MailerClient" instance?

In the documentation it is written "Then in your router definition, use the trait MailerComponents", with the following code example:

```
import play.api._
import play.api.ApplicationLoader.Context
import router.Routes
import play.api.libs.mailer._

class MyApplicationLoader extends ApplicationLoader {
  def load(context: Context) = {
    new ApplicationComponents(context).application
  }
}

class ApplicationComponents(context: Context) extends BuiltInComponentsFromContext(context) with MailerComponents {
  lazy val myComponent = new MyComponent(mailerClient)
  // create your controllers here ...
  lazy val router = new Routes(...) // inject your controllers here
}
```

(I have added "play.application.loader=SimpleApplicationLoader" in application.conf)

but I get the following compilation errors:

```
D:\myApp\app\SimpleApplicationLoader.scala:12: not found: type MailerComponents

[error] class ApplicationComponents(context: Context) extends BuiltInComponentsFromContext(context) with MailerComponents {
[error]                                                                                                  ^
[error] D:\myApp\app\SimpleApplicationLoader.scala:13: not found: value mailerClient
[error]   lazy val applicationController = new controllers.Mail(mailerClient)
[error]                                                         ^
[error] two errors found
[error] (compile:compileIncremental) Compilation failed
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can go with the run-time dependency injection, as the other answer has suggested. But if you want to go with your current approach, read on...

The problem is, the `MailerComponents` trait doesn't exist in the [3.x branch](https://github.com/playframework/play-mailer/blob/3.x/src/main/scala/play/api/libs/mailer/MailerPlugin.scala). it does seem to exist in the [master branch](https://github.com/playframework/play-mailer/blob/master/src/main/scala/play/api/libs/mailer/MailerPlugin.scala), but not in their [next branch](https://github.com/playframework/play-mailer/blob/next/src/main/scala/play/api/libs/mailer/MailerPlugin.scala). I am not sure what they are doing there.

If you want to continue with the example, you'll need to do a bit of fiddling and figure out how to make it compile. For ex. with a bit of looking around, I came up with the following.

```
import play.api._
import play.api.ApplicationLoader.Context
import router.Routes
import play.api.libs.mailer._

class SimpleApplicationLoader extends ApplicationLoader {
  def load(context: Context) = {
    new ApplicationComponents(context).application
  }
}

class ApplicationComponents(context: Context) extends BuiltInComponentsFromContext(context) {
  val mailerClient = new CommonsMailer(configuration)
  lazy val applicationController = new controllers.ApplicationScala(mailerClient)
  lazy val assets = new controllers.Assets(httpErrorHandler)
  lazy val router = new Routes(httpErrorHandler, applicationController)
}
```

Basically, instead of relying on the non-existent `MailerComponent` to create a mailerClient for me, I just did it myself.

If you have the following line in `controllers.ApplicationScala`

```
val id = mailer.configure(Configuration.from(Map("host" -> "typesafe.org", "port" -> 1234))).send(email)
```

Replace it with:

```
val id = mailer.send(email)
```

And it will compile. Meanwhile, I think I should raise an issue on github about this. And maybe you should.

Comment: Thanks Bhashit! As the current approach did not work, I was trying to send the emails with run-time dependency injection. Now, I can't understand how to invoke the sending.. I don't wish to do it with an Action, but to send a notification email each time one of several other Actions happen... if I try executing `controllers.Mailer.send()` from one of my Action function I get the following compilation error:  `object Mailer is not a member of package controllers
[error] Note: class Mailer exists, but it has no companion object. `

Comment: @Jenny it looks like you are not instantiating the Mailer class. You can't use  `controllers.Mailer.send()` directly (like you do in routes). If you are using run time DI, try injecting the Mailer instance into your controllers. And I think the Mailer class shouldn't be a part of the controller package.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you could simply let play framework inject the mail client. Setting up the configuration and annotating your constructor with `@Inject()` should work.
Declaration of your `Mail` controller would look like this:

```
class Mail @Inject() (mailer: MailerClient) {
```

Comment: Thanks Lukasz. With run-time dependency injection, I can't understand how to invoke the sending.. I don't wish to do it with an Action, but to send a notification email each time one of several other Actions happen... if I try executing `controllers.Mailer.send()` from one of my Action function I get the following compilation error: `object Mailer is not a member of package controllers [error] Note: class Mailer exists, but it has no companion object.`

Comment: well if you are in a different class and want to execute method of class Mail, you will need its instance that you can ask to be injected as well `class MyOtherClass @Inject() (mailer: Mailer)`